# Serving a portion of an `ifstream` object as an `istream`

Tags: c++, iterator, std, ifstream

This feels like a simple question; I'm a newbie when it comes to c++ magic.

I have a `ifstream` and a function that accepts `istream` as its single argument. I would like to pass it an object that will have the last couple of bytes/characters removed (or set to a certain length) but otherwise behave exactly like the original `ifstream` object. Ideally, without reading `ifstream`s contents at once to memory.

More specifically, I have a parsing function that's supposed to handle most of the file (except the last chunk) and I'd like to create a "view" of the same file stream where the final chunk is removed.

The file is guaranteed to not change and I know the length of the chunk I wanna parse in advance.

Thanks!

Comment: Slicing has a very specific meaning in C++ and it doesn't appear to be what you're talking about, especially since ifstreams can't be copied. You may want to consider describing your problem differently. As it is right now it's very hard to understand what you're talking ab out.

Comment: One option would be to write a custom `std::streambuf` that reads from the original `std::ifstream`'s `std::streambuf` but ignores the last bytes (or, at least returns only bytes up to the desired chunk size). Then you can construct a `std::istream` object using this custom `std::streambuf`, and then pass that `std:::istream` to the function instead of passing the `std::ifstream`

Comment: Have you tried anything to show us what you mean?

Comment: Hmm. Normally for things like this I would look at Boost's stream filters. But in this case, it sounds like a good idea to actually use the `std::streambuf` internal buffers.